# How do I Color a label in reporting services based on a value in the dataset?

Tags: c#, reportingservices-2005

I have an SQL Server 2005 Express Reporting Server and I'm trying update a report to show a coloured label based on a value stored in the database.

I currently store the colour as an aRGB value, but I can change this if required.

I've seen posts on how to use expression in the color property, but I can't embed c# there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found out that u have to use VB code.

Here's the steps.

1. Add a reference to System.Drawing in the report properties -> reference tab
2. Add this custom code to the report properties -> code tab

   Public Function GetMyColour(myColour as integer) as string
   Dim colorObj As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(myColour)

   return String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", colorObj.R, colorObj.G, colorObj.B)
   End Function
3. Set the color property expression on the report object you want set the color of to this

   =Code.GetMyColour(First(Fields!RecipeColour.Value, "StockControl"))

Comment: This looks really good, but the whole concept of adding assembly references to reports is new to me. When I click the ellipsis I am given an openFileDialog targeting dll's on my local machine. Where should I point it for this to work?

Comment: I got it working by manually entering the fully qualified assembly name (in this case: 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' - kindly provided by ILSpy). I still don't understand why I am given a local file browser.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS uses VB.NET, not C#, and most places will accept code, it is prefixed with a '=' to let the parser know that it is code. I don't know exactly where you are trying to set the label (in a table, in a floating textbox, etc), but it is very likely that it is doable.

Comment: Its in a floating textbox - Can I use something like Color.FromArgb(myDbValue)?