# SSRS report listing all available colors

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I would like to build a SSRS report that shows all the available colors (non-custom) in the web color pallet shown in Visual Studio (BIDS?).  I assume this can be done in code, probably with a reference to System.Drawing.Color, but I can't figure out a good way to achieve it.  I'm currently using ssrs 2005.

Something like:

```
Color Name | [Color]     | HTML code (bonus, not necessary)
---------------------------------------------------------------
Black      | [Black]     | #000000
White      | [White]     | #ffffff
DimGray    | [DimGray]   | #
...
LimeGreen  | [LimeGreen] | #
etc
```

I know I could build this manually, but I thought it would be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in how I solved this, I ended up manually building a simple union query with all the available colors as the datasource.  This wasn't a huge loss, because it opens up the door to some interesting database-driven color schemes in the future.

**The datasource**

```
--MainDS: manual list of colors in VS2005 system
Select 'Black' as [color_name] union all 
Select 'White' union all 
Select 'DimGray' union all 
Select 'Gray' union all 
Select 'DarkGray'
-- etc
```

**Show the color's HTML Color Code**

1. Report > Report Properties
2. Reference tab: Add System.Drawing
3. Code tab, add the function that follows

`Public Function HTMLColor(my_color as String) as String
  Dim colorObj As System.Drawing.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(my_color)
  return String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", colorObj.R, colorObj.G, colorObj.B)
End Function`

I got the meat of this function from another Stack question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5207560/103131

**Layout**

This made it easy to setup the report as a simple Table.  For the 3 original columns, I used these values:

```
[Color name] = (value)=Fields!color_name.value
[Color] = (BackgroundColor)=Fields!color_name.value
[White*] = (BackgroundColor)=White
[HTML] = =Code.HTMLColor(Fields!color_name.Value)
```

I also included an extra column of just white, which really helps see the subtle differences in some of the lighter shades.