# SSRS- Get Hex or int from color name

Tags: reporting-services, reporting-services-2016

Is there a way in SSRS code to convert a color name to hex or 3 ints of the a RGB value? ie convert "Silver" to 0xC0C0C0 or (192,192,192).

Comment: Have a look at this answer if you want to do it programatically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692926/ssrs-report-listing-all-available-colors

Or this which appears to just list them all out. It does not mention SSRS but the names look similar. https://www.nwds-ak.com/Web-Resources/Web-Design/Colors-By-Name-Hex

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alan,
I was able to find it from the first link. [SSRS report listing all available colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692926/ssrs-report-listing-all-available-colors)

System.Drawing.Color.FromName(my_color)